# How to model relationships on relationships?

Tags: neo4j, uml, cypher, relationships

I've to solve next problem:

I have 3 nodes:

```
(n:Node)-[r:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(a:Attr {name ="xxxx"}) ->(t:Type)
```

all the `a:Attr` nodes have :Translation associations:

```
(a) -> [:_HAS_TRANSLATION] -> (tr1:Translation {name : "yyyy", lang ="fr"})

(a) -> [:_HAS_TRANSLATION] -> (tr2:Translation {name : "kkkk", lang ="de"})
```

---

Now, I would like to use relationships to model the same things:

```
(n:Node)-[r:HAS_ATTRIBUTE {name ="xxxx"}]->(t:Type)
```

How can I add translation to the `HAS_ATTRIBUTE` name property, of course without adding new `_HAS_ATTRIBUTE` to the `n:Node`?

I should need to have such a thing as a RELATIONSHIP on the RELATIONSHIP ...

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm understanding your question.

Consider an intermediate node, e.g.

```
(n:Node)-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(attr:Attribute {name: "X")),
(attr)-[:HAS_TRANSLATION]->(tr1:Translation),
(attr)-[:HAS_TYPE]->(t:Type)
```

...or something of the like.  Note that "attr" would be the new, intermediate node (you can name the relationships whatever you please, obviously).

If you need to be more specific (e.g. instances of attributes), you can always replace "attr" with something like "specificAttr" and have "attr" point to "attr".

Intermediate nodes are a great way of tackling modeling questions like this where you need to qualify a relationship more fully.

Comment: Yes, but this exactly the original question, where the intermediate node is already present.
And my goal is to remove the intermediate node ....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to have only 2 nodes and one relationship, right?

To achieve this you can simply do

```
(n:Node)-[r:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->
(a:Attr {name ="xxxx", lang_fr="yyyy", lang_de="zzzz"})->
(t:Type)
```

Comment: No, this doen't solve the problem because I need to maintain distinct translation each one with an owner

Comment: In that case you really need that intermediary node.

Comment: And, IMHO, the ability to add relationships to relationships would be a great enhancement for Neo4j.

Comment: Then that's no longer a graph.

Comment: @PaoloDiPietro Can you clarify what you mean by "distinct translation each one with an owner"?